# Amend field - nvarchar(12) to nvarchar(20)

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, model-view-controller

I've been let down by my Programmer, so I need to change a field size myself today.

Basically, a field is limited to 12 characters on a form which I need to change to 20. I've logged on to the SQL database and changed it there, but its still not working on the main site.

I've been told I need to change it in FluentNHibernate, but I've never used it and don't know where to search for the field on the main server.

Can anyone help? I'm using c#, asp.net with mvc and FNH.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any string length convention defined in the model mapping

see FlunetNHibernate Wiki for reference http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping